# Plugin icon does not show in QGIS - how to make it show?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Nyk0qFJNZ4 and I installed the required plug-in (Multipart Split https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/) in QGIS. I cannot see any new icon in the toolbars even though "plug-in toolbars" is checked.

I have tried closing QGIS and opening it again, and restarting my computer, but it still doesn't appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plugin adds its icon to the "Advanced Digitizing Toolbar".

[image]